# How do you integrate comment plugin from your wordpress into your blog.php HTML page?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I've read, watched so many articles and videos and just can't seem to put my hands on one thing. Any help would be appreciated.

So here it goes..
I have a wordpress blog and that has been integrated into my website in the blog.php, so that people can see my blog from my website instead of being linked to wordpress.. I wanted my clients to post comments from my blog.php site and currently it's only showing the default comment_form part(which is too big and not what I wanted) So I installed comments plugin called "DISQUS", but currently it's only showing up on my wordpress page and not my website at blog.php.
Could there be a php code that I'm missing to post on my blog.php?

So far this is what I have on the top of the blog.php page

```
<?php require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');?>
```

and where I'm showing my blog part

```
 <?php require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');?>
 <?php  get_header();?>
 <?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=orderby=post_date'); ?>
 <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
 <?php the_title(); ?> 
 <?php the_time('m/d/y') ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php comment_form(); ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So am I missing something here? Should I be changing comment_form into something else? Or am I completely off?

Thanks Everyone.